# Embedding Lua modules on C side

Tags: c, lua

I want to provide user with several custom functions to use, but hide it's implementation to ship it as a simple DLL.
So user just link the dll and plugin works as is. Several tables, integers etc are declared dynamically on C side, but declaring "classes", table-oriented functions from C makes the code unreadable.
Is there a way to embed Lua module in a header, for example, and preload it so the main script user loads with **luaL_loadfile** will be able to access it?
Of course I can dirty-hack it by inserting code into user's script, but it seems to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to embed Lua module in a header, for example, and preload it so the main script user loads with luaL_loadfile will be able to access it?

Yes. You can use [bin2c.lua](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BinToCee) (or any alternative listed on bottom).

Here is a real-world example from a project named [fakeredis.c](https://github.com/deltheil/fakeredis.c):

The `Makefile` contains a dedicated target that creates a header made of Lua bytecode of the various modules to embed:

```
fklua.h:
    @echo "converting lua -> C..."
    @./lua2c.sh
```

*(behind the scenes `lua2c.sh` uses `bin2c.lua`)*

For example the project contains a module named [fmtreply.lua](https://github.com/deltheil/fakeredis.c/blob/1515887/modules/fmtreply.lua). Once converted this module is simply defined as a byte array:

```
/* fklua.h */

/* this is the name of the main function the module exposes */
#define FK_LUA_FMTREPLY "_fmtreply"

/* this is the byte code of the module obtained with `bin2c.lua` */
static const unsigned char fk_lua_fmtreply[]={45, 45, 32, ...};
```

Then the module is explicitly loaded within the main library by means of [`luaL_loadbuffer`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_loadbuffer) (see [here](https://github.com/deltheil/fakeredis.c/blob/00e7ec9/fkredis.c#L106) and [there](https://github.com/deltheil/fakeredis.c/blob/00e7ec9/fkredis.c#L27-L35) for more details).

Comment: The only thing I want to add: isn't it better to use **xxd -i binary_file** instead? It will produce ready to use file

Comment: Yes you can use `luac` and `xxd` as an alternative (the `-i` option is convenient). In my case what I did is an equivalent.